# PTR запись домена

Tags: dns, hosting, cloudflare

подскажите, если сайт хостится на хостинге, например hetzner и имеет IP 5.8.67.13 (IP вымышленный), трафик проксируется через cloudflare (как я понял, ибо IP уже меняется на 104.28.2.131, в WHOIS стоит организация CloudFlare) то где и с какими значениями необходимо прописать PTR (RDNS) запись?
Я прописал в cloudflare `131.2.28.104.in-addr.arpa site.ru`, эффекта это не принесло. У хостера прописана запись `5.8.67.13 site.ru` в RDNS

Comment: А позвольте поинтересоваться, для чего вам PTR?

Comment: @andreymal для доставки почты же

Comment: @DaemonHK почта отправляется не через cloudflare, так что скорее всего нет

Comment: @DaemonHK ну и в любом случае для почты важны в первую очередь SPF, DKIM и DMARC, а PTR это штука второстепенная

Comment: @andreymal тем не менее некоторые сервисы заворачивают письма обратно без нее

Comment: @DaemonHK тем не менее почта всё ещё делается не через cloudflare, а без cloudflare у автора с PTR всё в порядке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего, вопрос возник ввиду необходимости отправки почтовых сообщений с вашего сервера.

1. если для отправки сообщений вы используете какой-либо **иной** сервер в качестве ретранслятора (так называмого «[smarthost](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_host)»), то о наличии и корректности [rdns-записи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80_DNS) беспокоиться вообще не имеет смысла.
2. если же ваш сервер отправляет сообщения самостоятельно, то rdns-запись, естественно, должна быть прописана для того ip-адреса, с которого и будут отправляться сообщения.